# Android SoundPool does not open many tracks / How to create CBR OGG files?

Tags: android, soundpool, ogg, audacity

I am trying to load some tracks in a SoundPool and switch between them based on some conditions.

In the beginning not even the first track would start playing, with the following error displayed:

```
10-23 22:11:07.240: E/AudioTrack(16803): AudioFlinger could not create track, status: -12
10-23 22:11:07.240: E/SoundPool(16803): Error creating AudioTrack
```

I did some research on Google and ended up in saving the MP3 files in OGG format and reducing their duration as much as possible. The duration of each file is about 3 seconds, and I put them on infinite loop using the same SoundPool object. I used Audacity to export them in the OGG format, but Audacity does not support ConstantBitRate, which I am supposed to use according to several articles / questions I found about the SoundPool.

This allowed 2 sound files to be loaded, but when I try to start a 3rd file, this error comes up again.

```
10-23 22:11:07.240: E/AudioTrack(16803): AudioFlinger could not create track, status: -12
10-23 22:11:07.240: E/SoundPool(16803): Error creating AudioTrack
```

How can I get all 3 files to play simultaneously?

EDIT: The activity's code is the following.

```
private SoundPool soundPool;
private AudioManager audioManager;
private float actVolume;
private float maxVolume;
private float volume;
private boolean mainPlaying;
private Integer clean = -1;
private Integer filter1 = -1;
private Integer filter2 = -1;
private Integer[] mainAudios = new Integer[] { clean, filter1, filter2 };
private int remaining;

// ...

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // /////////////////////////////// AUDIO
    audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
    actVolume = (float) audioManager
            .getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    maxVolume = (float) audioManager
            .getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    volume = actVolume / maxVolume;
    setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

    soundPool = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {

        @Override
        public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId,
                int status) {
            remaining--;
            if (remaining == 0) {
                mainAudios = new Integer[] { clean, filter1, filter2 };
                for (int id : mainAudios)
                    soundPool.play(id, 0, 0, 1, -1, 1f);
                mainPlaying = true;
            }
        }
    });

    remaining = mainAudios.length;
    clean = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.angle_normal, 1);
    filter1 = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.filter2, 1);
    filter2 = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.filter5, 1);

    // //////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // ...

}
```

Comment: post your activity code

Comment: did my answer help you out ?

Comment: @j2emanue not really... my audio files are already very small. Sometimes not even one starts to play. As for the source itself, I don't see any major differences from mine... Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

status: -12 is some kind of memory error.  You have 3 sound files which is fine but there is memory constraint depending on the device memory.  I'd shrink your sound files to like 25kb each or something close. Try small files and it should work.   I used my own sound files which were very small and it works fine.  But when i put in large files i got the status -12 error.

If you want an example of how i would have structured your code though:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private AudioManager audioManager;
private float actVolume;
private float maxVolume;
private float volume;

SoundPool sp;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
    actVolume = (float) audioManager
            .getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    maxVolume = (float) audioManager
            .getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    volume = actVolume / maxVolume;
    setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    sp.release();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();

//put your own resources here
        int[] resources = {R.raw.whatsup, R.raw.monkey,
                R.raw.sneeze, R.raw.aww };
        sp = new SoundPool(resources.length, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
        sp.setOnLoadCompleteListener(listener);

        for (int id : resources)
            sp.load(this, id, 1);

    }
OnLoadCompleteListener listener = new OnLoadCompleteListener() {
    String TAG = "main";

    @Override
public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int id, int status) {

            if (status == 0)
                switch (id) {
    //this switch is just to demo you can collect your variables here for each sound id thats loaded

            case 1:
                    Log.d(TAG, "sound id:"+ id +" loaded");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Log.d(TAG, "sound id:"+ id +" loaded");
                    break;
            case 3:
                Log.d(TAG, "sound id:"+ id +" loaded");
                break;

            case 4:
                Log.d(TAG, "sound id:"+ id +" loaded");
                break;

            }
        Log.d(TAG, "playing:" + id);
        soundPool.play(id, volume, volume, 0, -1, 1f);

    }
};
}
```